# Getting Nginx to forward to Thin on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, nginx, thin

I'm struggling to get Nginx to proxy my :80 traffic onto my thin cluster.

At the moment.. nothing happens. See http://ec2-50-19-75-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

See below for my config files:

My **etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dankit** config file looks likes this

```
upstream thin {
     server 0.0.0.0:3000;
     server 0.0.0.0:3001;
     server 0.0.0.0:3002;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ec2-50-19-174-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

    root /home/ubuntu/apps/dankit-rails;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect false;

      if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
      }
      if (-f $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
      }
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://thin;
        break;
      }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root html;
    }
}
```

I then ran:
sudo ln -s sites-available/dankit sites-enabled/dankit

**/etc/thin/dankit.yml**

```
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
address: 0.0.0.0
timeout: 30
port: 3000
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []

max_persistent_conns: 512
environment: production
servers: 3
daemonize: true
chdir: /home/ubuntu/apps/dankit-rails
```

and just to confirm both are running:

ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-06-7A-F8:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ps -ef | grep -i thin
root       923     1  2 16:06 ?        00:00:09 thin server (0.0.0.0:3000)
root       934     1  1 16:06 ?        00:00:09 thin server (0.0.0.0:3001)
root       945     1  1 16:06 ?        00:00:08 thin server (0.0.0.0:3002)
ubuntu     971   817  0 16:14 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i thin
ubuntu@domU-12-31-39-06-7A-F8:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ ps -ef | grep -i nginx
root       542     1  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data   545   542  0 16:04 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process

---

My thin servers start OK and the logs in the rails dir don't show any errors.

I'm starting to think it's a security issue with an ec2 security group. I have however added TCP for 0.0.0.0/0 3000-3030 and the usual :80 and ssh.

This is driving me mental! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I then ran: sudo ln -s sites-available/dankit sites-enabled/dankit`

The issue may be one of two things or both:

1. ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/dankit /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dankit
2. chown nobody:nobody /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dankit

I tend only to use the full path for the symbolic links ... maybe it's just a good habit, but I also found that nginx isn't happy if the permissions aren't configured right for enabled sites.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change all the 0.0.0.0's to 127.0.0.1 or localhost which points to 127.0.0.1. The difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1 is that the former refers to the localhost's physical interface(s), while the latter refers to a software interface.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Changed the IP, restarted nginx and thin but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this URL http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/5/27/ubuntu-hardy-nginx-rails-and-thin & your configuration match perfect, I don't think of any problem, though I would like you to verify few things.

Please verify the following stuffs:

1. Change thin address to point to `127.0.0.1`
2. Make sure the firewall is OPEN for the port-number of thin & 80 for TCP connection. Not by looking at the amazon console but by running `iptables` command.
3. Finally, make sure, your public-dns is `CORRECT`

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.

**Anyone that can answer why the symlink was the problem can get the answer!**

Thanks for all the feedback and help. Basically if anyone else runs into this problem... here's what it was.

I noticed when I removed configs from /etc/nginx/site-enabled it affected the server.

..OK that sounds right!

Now I noticed when I re-sym linked a config from /etc/nginx/site-available to /etc/nginx/site-enabled it had no effect. Even the default nginx default config didn't work.

so! there must be a problem here with symlink. I did a quick test by importing /etc/nginx/site-available/dankit into the main Nginx config and hey! site is up.

Therefore I believe my symlink command:

```
sudo ln -s sites-available/dankit sites-enabled/dankit
```

is bollocks. I gotta look into another solution.